# Need help scaling in o3d

Tags: scaling, o3d

I have been having trouble find much documentation on o3d (not too surprisingly).  Does anyone know how to scale my x in o3d?

Comment: Could you be slightly more specific?

Comment: I have a large positionArray that defines the vertices for that are used to make up my cube but I need to scale these values by .6.  Right now I just run through a loop and multiply each of the x vertices by .6 but I think it would make more sense to some just do a some sort of scale x call.  So I assume I would get the transformation matrix and then give it a call that would look something like this: matrix.scaleX(.6) but I don't know.  If I would have to enter the whole matrix that would be fine but does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the o3djs.math module there is a function:

```
o3djs.math.matrix4.scaling = function(v) ...
```

where "v" is a vector. So if you have a current transformation matrix you could do:

```
var scaleMatrix = o3djs.math.matrix4.scaling( [0.6, 1, 1] );
var newMatrix = o3djs.math.mulMatrixMatrix4(scaleMatrix, currMatrix);
```

The "newMatrix" would scale the X dimension of the cube by 0.6 and then apply "currMatrix" after that.